# apduToolTask cannot be found

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu

i am new to java card platform and presently i am using java card classic edition v 3.0.1 and when i am using Apache ANT command - **ant all** to build the build.xml file, i am getting the following error:

c:\java\java_card_kit-2_2_2\samples\build.xml:17: taskdef class com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.APDUToolTask cannot be found

I've already followed the instructions to the point where it asks me to setup the System path of ANT as well. I'm using ANT 1.8.1.

can someone please help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Continue by following instructions from next sections "Installing the Ant Tasks" and "Library Dependencies" from java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows.zip\java_card_kit-2_2_2\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-ant-tasks.zip\ant-tasks\docs\pdf\ant-user-guide.pdf, pages 4-5.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I am using java card kit 2.2.2.

When you say "continue...", which page do you refer to?  Where can I find these 2 sections?

Thanks in advance.